# Qt 4.6.2 - QPropertyAnimation not works

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qt4, nokia

I have a problem.
I use a QPropertyAnimation to move a QLabel but not works.

```
void TitleChannel::changeChannel(float angle){
   int channel=(int)(angle/60);

   QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "geometry");
            animation->setDuration(10000);
            animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 360, 200));
            animation->setEndValue(QRect(0, 240, 360, 200));
            animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutElastic);
   animation->start();
}
```

"label" is a Qlabel pointer that is a parameter of constructor. 
I also use the property "pos" but not works.
The "label" start into QRect(0, 0, 360, 200) but not move into QRect(0, 240, 360, 200)
any help?
Thanks

Comment: I print whit qDebug on the screen the state and the currentTime of the animation.
The state is always 2 (running) and the currentTime is always 0.
I Forget to tell you that i'm working on Nokia N97.

Answer (score 1):

It works well on desktop. Have you tried declaring QPropertyAnimation *animation; in the header file and initialize it on constructor then use it on your function there?

Because regardless of the platform the animation should work, I am using QPropertyAnimation on a Nokia 5800 as well.